# How do I attach my application into another .Net application?

Tags: c#, .net, build-process

I'm trying to create a quick debugger, wherein I can attach my application to a running .net process and execute scripts from there. I'm using C#.

How will I do it?

Thanks :)

Comment: I think you need to provide more details. Why not execute the scripts from the already running process? Why create a new app?

Comment: When we are deploying an app to client, we can use the application to attach to a running process and examine some globals and execute operations within.

Answer (score 1):

You can attach to a process in Visual Studio and use VS tools for debugging.  What does your application do that would require it to be attached to other processes outside of VS?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6wf8e4z.aspx

Comment: The application should be small, and there will be no codes to step into. I'll be pushing those scripts in the running process.